# Improve Accuracy Intel Real Sense Speech Recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, intel

How can we improve accuracy in speech recognition. Currently i am using Commands and Dictionary. Are there any more ways to improve this further. Can we create an audio dictionary as well such  that a particular audio should be recognized as a particular sentence.

```
 PXCMSpeechRecognition sr;
   session.CreateImpl<PXCMSpeechRecognition>(out sr);
   // sr is a PXCMSpeechRecognition instance.

            String[] cmds = new String[9] { "Switch on",  
                  "Light Off",
                 "Up",
                 "Down",
                 "Raise",
                 "Two",
                 "Three",
                 "Four",
                 "Five"
              };

            // Build the grammar.
            sr.BuildGrammarFromStringList(1, cmds, null);

            // Set the active grammar.
            sr.SetGrammar(1);
```

Comment: Can't seem to find any online docs for the Intel SR engine, but in general, command & control systems work much better when you have a "garbage" rule to catch out-of-grammar inputs.   Otherwise, the system tries *really hard* to match to a particular rule, and often will generate false positives.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Volume up [Take a look](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?setvolume_pxcaudiosource.html)

I think if you set your volume  up  the system can recognize better.

As the man said to you , you have to limit your dictionary, but be careful if there are words with a seem pronunciation , maybe it may confuse the sound.
  EXAMPLE :

```
   public void recognize(){

        PXCMAudioSource audioSource = session.CreateAudioSource();
        audioSource.SetVolume(1f);
        ....

      }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10306499)

Comment: I did it , but I don't understand why I got negative vote

Comment: I left the comment, which is constructive feedback, but didn't down vote. Sometimes folks will down vote without leaving an explanation, but my guess is it's for the same reason I made the comment during the standard StackOverflow review process.

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve is to limit your dictionary to expected commands, phrases. That way instead of checking thru 50k words, it can be much smaller.